# Laravel email notification not updating content

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-notification

Email notification content is not updating when making changes on the Notification class.

Tried

```
php artisan view:clear

php artisan queue:restart

php artisan cache:clear
```

but content still not updating.

Comment: please add your files - classes ? to know more about your problem :)

Comment: are you using supervisor ?

Comment: I have faced the similar issue a while ago. Have a look at it

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51895025/laravel-5-5-email-notification-not-updating-conten

Comment: @faizan.sh not using supervisor. Yeah ive already read that article but no luck

Comment: @SaifManwill There's no problem with the code I think. Cause I tried deleting the Notification class but the email notification still gets sent even without the file. It's weird.